# Will a WIFI repeater act as a WIFI-to-Ethernet bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, bridge

Due to a lapse by the electrician (who laid the cat6 cables and wired the sockets), one Cat6 cable did not reach the Rack. It is on the other side of the garage and I don’t want a messy cable up the wall, across the ceiling, and down the wall.

I was looking at using a Wi-fi extender as a Wifi-to-Ethernet Bridge. Would this work?

An example device can be [found here](https://www.jaycar.co.nz/n300-wi-fi-range-extender/p/YN8370).

The specs are

> This intelligent Wi-Fi device can handle it all. Use it as a repeater to extend the range of your existing Wi-Fi network, provides a Wi-Fi access point for your wired network, or even acts as a router for your existing modem. It connects straight into your mains power outlet for no fuss installation, and configuration is quick and painless (with ultra-simple WPS connectivity supported too). Suitable for 802.11b/g/n standards up to 300mbps, supporting modern standards for security too. It also features integrated status LEDs for signal strength, as well as quick reference of network status.
>
> Features:
>
> - Repeater, Access Point, or Router
> - Supports up to 300Mbps
> - One-Button WPS Connect
>
> Specifications:
>
> - Wi-Fi Standards: 802.11b / g / n
> - Security Support: 64/128/152-bit WEP, WPA-PSK, WPA-2-PSK, WPA/WPA2

Comment: “Due to a lapse by the sparky…” Is “sparky” an “electrician” in your local colloquial language? Curious because that sentence confused me. I assume so since this appears to be a wiring issue.

Comment: Yes, updated the question.

Comment: The manual is remarkably useless in this aspect - It actually dosen't say you can, but I don't see any reason why it *shouldn't* work

Comment: I found a TPLink one at another store which says that it will do it (for Media devices ROFL - How does it know they are media devices).

Comment: A network device is a network device. It shouldn't.

Comment: Are you referring to https://www.pbtech.co.nz/product/NETTPL3020/TP-Link-TL-MR3020-Travel-Wi-Fi-Router-Wireless-N15 - that should work for you - but be mindful that its eifi interface means you will lilely get < 100 megabit throughput.

Comment: Also, do you happen to know if your electrical switches are on thr same subcircuit? If so an ethernet over power solution - while more expensive - may be faster and more reliable.

Comment: @davidgo - they are at the moment.  But won't be for long as they will be on different UPSs

Comment: @RohitGupta - not sure if the email I attempted to send you got to you. I suspect we are both in/near Albany. Would you like to meet and maybe we can work out a better solution then wifi (no charge, I'm curious to catch up with you). I wonder if we can do a network cable join, pull a new cable or even split the existing cable into 2 100 megabit pairs?

Comment: @davidgo - No I haven't seen any emails.  How did you send it ?  I have sent one your website

Comment: @RohitGupta Got it.  Sent you txt.  Hope to catch up soon.